# What is the term for something who is not part of any group

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, functions

I have multiple elements. Some of the elements have been associated with some particular group while some other are still alone (they are not part of any group)
Can you please suggest some term/word for such lonely element?

Comment: Miscellaneous and sundry?

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I can't use Sundry because all of my elements  are of same kind and have equal importance. Some of the elements just have not become part of any group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **singleton** is defined (in one of its senses) as

> singleton n ...
>
> 2. a single object, individual, etc, separated or distinguished from a pair or group

[[Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/singleton)]

For people (and your question needs tightening), a 'singleton' is a fairly rare word for a person not part of an 'item', and 'loner' would be more appropriate.

Comment: I think this would work well. Regarding application to people: I've most often seen *singleton* used to distinguish from twins, triplets, etc. ("Singleton pregnancies are much less fraught than multiple pregnancies"; "I have twins who are eight, and my singleton is five.") or as a label for a person without a date where one might be expected, as at a wedding ("*Wedding Guest Etiquette* DON'T: Look like a desperate singleton!" —from an actual online article).

Answer (score 1):

I think SINGLETON may be the word you are after, but since it is not clear to me what your "elements" are (things? effects? people? creations? groups? types?) you may want to toy with ISOLATE (as a noun, unless the context is just plain wrong), LONE (as Ashworth suggested), INDIVIDUAL, SINGULAR, or even just ONE.  Best of luck.